Schedule a task to run when a program is ended
My code looks like this:
    <QueryList>
      <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
        <Select Path="Security">
         *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] 
         and Task = 13313 
         and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) 
         and (EventID=4689)]] 
         and *[EventData[(
               Data='C:\Program Files (x86)\GOG Galaxy\GalaxyClient.exe'
               )]]
        </Select>
      </Query>
    </QueryList>

However, It Runs the task both when the program is opened and when the program is ended




     *[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing'] and Task = 13313 and (band(Keywords,9007199254740992)) and (EventID=4689)]] 
   and
     *[EventData[(Data='C:\Program Files (x86)\GOG Galaxy\GalaxyClient.exe')]]
    


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you tried an alternative, i.e., batch file to A. run progam and B. perform other task when it closes?
